# How do I list all adresses changed after a certain date in a multi call?

Tags: api

I'm using the magento soap v1 api, and I wish to get all the adresses changed after a certain datetime. 
I’m using php to setup the connection and fetch the data.

I have the following users to play with:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '2',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-07 12:30:32',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:19:30',
      'city' => 'Weaverville',
      'country_id' => 'US',
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Doe  ',
      'postcode' => '96093',
      'region' => 'American Samoa',
      'region_id' => '3',
      'street' => 'Street line 1
Streer line 2',
      'telephone' => '530-623-2513',
      'is_default_billing' => false,
      'is_default_shipping' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '3',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-07 12:36:30',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:19:30',
      'city' => 'Weaverville',
      'country_id' => 'US',
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Doe',
      'postcode' => '96093',
      'region' => 'American Samoa',
      'region_id' => '3',
      'street' => 'Street line 1
Streer line 2',
      'telephone' => '530-623-2513',
      'is_default_billing' => false,
      'is_default_shipping' => false,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '4',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-14 10:49:59',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:15:01',
      'city' => 'abc town',
      'country_id' => 'NL',
      'firstname' => 'john',
      'lastname' => 'doe',
      'postcode' => 'dsddf eh',
      'region_id' => '0',
      'street' => 'hohoho 47
mwhgahahahaha',
      'telephone' => '31645494440',
      'is_default_billing' => true,
      'is_default_shipping' => true,
    ),
  ),
,
```

They are my customers in magento. 
Now if I do a multicall constructed with the following array

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'customer_address.list',
    1 => '1',
    2 => 
    array (
      'updated_at' => 
      array (
        'from' => '2013-03-07 11:25:30',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'customer_address.list',
    1 => '2',
    2 => 
    array (
      'updated_at' => 
      array (
        'from' => '2013-03-07 11:25:30',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'customer_address.list',
    1 => '3',
    2 => 
    array (
      'updated_at' => 
      array (
        'from' => '2013-03-07 11:25:30',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'customer_address.list',
    1 => '4',
    2 => 
    array (
      'updated_at' => 
      array (
        'from' => '2013-03-07 11:25:30',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I’m **expecting** to see only the updated adresses after 11:25:30.

My expectations are not becoming true though. I get all adresses returned to me from the magento api.

How can I filter this with a multi call so that I only get adresses that have changed after a certain datetime?

This is what is returned to me

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '1',
      'created_at' => '2012-03-27 13:00:28',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:13:00',
      'city' => 'amsterdam',
      'country_id' => 'NL',
      'firstname' => 'johnny',
      'lastname' => 'camaro',
      'postcode' => '90210',
      'region_id' => '0',
      'street' => 'sssss 36',
      'telephone' => '03154444442',
      'is_default_billing' => true,
      'is_default_shipping' => true,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '2',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-07 12:30:32',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:19:30',
      'city' => 'Weaverville',
      'country_id' => 'US',
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Doe  ',
      'postcode' => '96093',
      'region' => 'American Samoa',
      'region_id' => '3',
      'street' => 'Street line 1
Streer line 2',
      'telephone' => '530-623-2513',
      'is_default_billing' => false,
      'is_default_shipping' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '3',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-07 12:36:30',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:19:30',
      'city' => 'Weaverville',
      'country_id' => 'US',
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Doe',
      'postcode' => '96093',
      'region' => 'American Samoa',
      'region_id' => '3',
      'street' => 'Street line 1
Streer line 2',
      'telephone' => '530-623-2513',
      'is_default_billing' => false,
      'is_default_shipping' => false,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'customer_address_id' => '4',
      'created_at' => '2013-01-14 10:49:59',
      'updated_at' => '2013-03-07 11:15:01',
      'city' => 'abc town',
      'country_id' => 'NL',
      'firstname' => 'john',
      'lastname' => 'doe',
      'postcode' => '7043491 eh',
      'region_id' => '0',
      'street' => 'hohoho 47
mwhgahahahaha',
      'telephone' => '444444444',
      'is_default_billing' => true,
      'is_default_shipping' => true,
    ),
  )
```

etc… my characters are finished…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with API V1 or V2.
The Address list method only accepts a parameter: `$customerId`.
The method being called in both V1 and V2 API is `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Api::items($customerId)`.

From my point of view you have 2 options.
1. Get all the addresses from all the customers and process them in your application. This could work if you have a small number of customers and addresses. Once the website grows this might turn out to be a memory black hole.
2. Create a custom module with API that fits your needs. Here are some instructions on how to do it:
[For V1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/custom_api_complete_example)
[For V2](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/)

Comment: Your answer comes closest to an acceptable soltion.
I now use a different solution by simply connecting to the database and reading it live from the database.
Much faster too ;-) But thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use complex filters mechanism, however, it is available in SOAP V2 only.
In SOAP V1 you can only use simple filters ('field' => 'value'), which are converted to 'eq' expression.

Comment: Do you know a place where there's proper soap v2 documentation?

Comment: Here is the documentation with filters example http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAPAPIVersionv2

However SOAP V1 example seems to be invalid.

Comment: I asked proper documentation... The soap v2 api is explained in  no usefull way.